# get many value from json

Tags: android, json, arraylist, location

I need to get latitude and longitude to my android, it got many values like this : 
[image]

I tried this to get values from JSON :

```
ArrayList<String> longitude;
ArrayList<String> latitude;

public void parseJson(String result) {
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                latitude.add(jo.getString("Latitude").toString());
                longitude.add(jo.getString("Longitude").toString());
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

But When I check the size of array, it's empty. 
Anyone can help or suggest my wrong ? Thanks

@after modified,I still got 0 size of array. So,I tried to search where it's stop by Toast then I found :

```
public void parseJson(String result) throws JSONException {

        longitude = new ArrayList<String>();
        latitude = new ArrayList<String>();

        JSONArray jArray = (JSONArray)JSONValue.parse(result);

        for (Object obj: jArray) {

            JSONObject jo = (JSONObject)obj;
            //here is when I toast it's got nothing
            latitude.add(jo.get("Latitude").toString());
            longitude.add(jo.get("Longitude").toString());
        }

    }
```

@aroth I got an answer!! I back to use my way like this :

```
public void parseJson(String result) throws JSONException {

        longitude = new ArrayList<String>();
        latitude = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            latitude.add(jo.getString("Latitude").toString());
            longitude.add(jo.getString("Longitude").toString());
        }
```

I think I forgot declare these:

```
         longitude = new ArrayList<String>();
         latitude = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I still no idea why your code is not work. However, thank a lot for your help :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json.org library is needlessly obtuse with its `get<Type>` methods that all pointlessly throw `JSONException`, I would recommend switching to [simple-json](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/).  Then you could do:

```
ArrayList<String> longitude;
ArrayList<String> latitude;

public void parseJson(String result) {
    longitude = new ArrayList<String>();
    latitude = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONArray jArray = (JSONArray)JSONValue.parse(result);
    for (Object obj : jArray) {
        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject)obj;
        latitude.add(jo.get("Latitude").toString());
        longitude.add(jo.get("Longitude").toString());
    }

}

//a simple test case
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = "[{\"Latitude\": \"1.23\", \"Longitude\": \"1.23\"}, \n{\"Latitude\": \"1.23\", \"Longitude\": \"1.23\"}, \n{\"Latitude\": \"1.23\", \"Longitude\": \"1.23\"}]";    
    MyParser parser = new MyParser();
    parser.parseJson(json);

    //should print:  3, 3
    System.out.println(parser.latitude.size() + ", " + parser.longitude.size());
}
```

Should work, assuming your input JSON matches your example snippet.

Comment: It's got errors at JSONValue (seem to it does not have this class) and at jArray at for(Object obj: jArray) "can only iterate an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable"

Comment: @Daisy - Yes, as I mentioned you will first need to get rid of the json.org library that you are currently using, and replace it with the [simple-json](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) version.  Then (assuming you are using Eclipse) just do a `Ctrl + Shift + O` to fix up your imports and you should be good to go.

Comment: Sorry and Thanks but  jArray at for(Object obj: jArray) stills getting an error

Comment: @Daisy - It's possible that not all the imports were cleaned up.  Can you check your imports and verify that you have `org.json.simple.JSONArray` and *not* `org.json.JSONArray`?

Comment: I fixed the import. When I checked size, it's got 0(zero).

Comment: @Daisy - Can you print out the string that you are passing to parseJson(), and then copy/paste it into your post?  If both libraries are returning 0, then it sounds like there is an issue with the input data.  Also, did you try the basic test-case that I included in the example code?  Does that also return a size of 0?

Comment: Yes, I tried ur test-case and still got zero. The string that I passing to parseJson() can see @picture above(dark gray background)

Comment: @Daisy - Got me then.  I've no idea why it's not working for you.  It works when I try it locally.  Maybe post the code that is calling `parseJson()`, and the code you are using to check the length of the result?

Answer (score 0):

try using gson library. It's compact and fast.

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Comment: Can gson deserialize a generic JSON-object into a Map, or do you need to specify a concrete container class for each flavor of JSON-object that you want to deserialize?

Comment: Gson does not have a built in mechanism to deserialize a JSON object of arbitrary complexity into a Map.  Doing so requires manual processing.  Jackson can do it in one simple line of code.  I posted examples using Gson and Jackson to do this at http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/06/gson-v-jackson.html  Search for the phrase "one simple line of code".